# Does dissolution and crystallization always occur together?

Tags: solutions

Does dissolution and crystallization always take place simultaneously?

Also does crystallization also occur in unsaturated solution but its rate is less than rate of dissolution or is rate of crystallization 0?

Comment: Getting to, and staying at, thermodynamic equilibrium is a dynamic process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first question:

Yes, crystallisation and dissolution takes place simultaneously.

When a solid solute is added to the solvent, some solute dissolves and its concentration increases in solution. This process is known as dissolution.

Some solute particles in solution collide with the solid solute particles and get separated out of solution. This process is known as crystallisation.

For your next question:

Crystallization rate is NOT 0 even in unsaturated solution.

As I have already mentioned crystallisation occur simultaneously when solute is getting dissolved.

But the rate of crystallisation is less than rate of dissolution that's why amount of solute being dissolved is more that amount of solute being crystallised.

Comment: Are you really saying that in an unsaturated solution there actually is crystallisation happening? That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I am taking reference to my book according to which some dissolved atoms collide with solid solute particles and get separated out. But the rate of crystallisation is lower than rate of dissolution so we don't see actual crystals separating out. As more and more solute keeps on dissolving the rate of crystallisation and dissolution come in equilibrium and no more solute dissolve. My book : NCERT Chemistry Part 1 Class 12

Comment: An unsaturated solution is a homogeneous phase, there is no solid. What you state only holds for a dissolution process, or saturated solutions. It doesn't even hold for super-saturated solutions as you need a nucleation site.